# Is Unit of Work more efficient if I don't care for transactions etc?

Tags: nhibernate, unit-of-work

If I have 10 database calls on my web page, and none of them require any transactions etc.
They are simply getting data from the database (reads), should I still use the unit of work class?

Is it because creating a new session per database call is too expensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NHibernate, session factory creation is very expensive (so you'll want to cache the session factory once it's created, probably on the `HttpApplication`) but session creation is very cheap. In other words, if it keeps your code cleaner, multiple session creations is not necessarily a bad thing. I think the NH documentation says it best:

> An ISessionFactory is an
>   expensive-to-create, threadsafe object
>   intended to be shared by all
>   application threads. An ISession is an
>   inexpensive, non-threadsafe object
>   that should be used once, for a single
>   business process, and then discarded.

So, using the UoW pattern is probably not *more* efficient due to the extra overhead, but it's a good practice and the overhead is probably not going to hurt you. Premature optimization and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use a transaction.  From Ayende's blog:

"NHibernate assume that all access to the database is done under a transaction, and strongly discourage any use of the session without a transaction."

For more details, here's a link to his blog posting:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/28/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged.aspx